# svg arc path getBBox result is wrong when the coordnate is very big in Chrome

Tags: svg

There is a path element of `"M 1050000 80 A 40 40 0 1 0 1050000 40"`, getBBox() result width and height are: `0.0000711679458618164, 0.00007629334868397564`

If move the path 10000 pixels towards left, become `"M 1040000 80 A 40 40 0 1 0 1040000 40"`, then getBBox() result width and height are: `74.625, 79.99937438964844`

The element's width and height are not changed but getBBox() give different results.

What's the reason and how to avoid this issue ? getBoundingClientRect() ?

Testing snippets:

```js
function $$(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

var b1 = $$("p1").getBBox();
$$("r1").innerHTML=('p1: width:'+b1.width +', height:'+ b1.height);
//0.0000711679458618164, 0.00007629334868397564

var b2 = $$("p2").getBBox();
$$("r2").innerHTML=('p2: width:'+b2.width +', height:'+ b2.height); 
//74.625, 79.99937438964844
```

```html
<svg width="110" height="110" viewBox="1050000 0 110 110">
<path id="p1" d="M 1050000 80 A 40 40 0 1 0 1050000 40" stroke="#880000" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></path>
</svg>

<svg width="110" height="110" viewBox="1040000 0 110 110">
<path id="p2" d="M 1040000 80 A 40 40 0 1 0 1040000 40" stroke="#880000" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></path>
</svg>


<p id="r1"></p>
<p id="r2"></p>
```

Comment: All UAs have issues when co-ordinates get large. Use a scale transform to avoid such big numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Has confirmed this is a bug of chromium: [issue 678162](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=678162). It's originally caused by the code bug of [Skia engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skia_Graphics_Engine). The fixing is committed.

Only some versions of Chrome has this bug. As my testing, Chrome 52 is ok, Chrome 55 has bug.

On my case, I just need to multiple the wrong bbox by 0x100000.

```
0.0000711679458618164 * 0x100000 == 74.625  
0.00007629334868397564 * 0x100000 == 79.99937438964844
```

Finally I use a custom function to calculate bbox for chrome.

This function cannot handle the nested svg(s) or nested transforms.

```
function bbox (element) {
    var svg = element.farthestViewportElement,
        mtr = element.getScreenCTM().inverse(),
        bcr = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x1 = bcr.left, x2 = bcr.right,
        y1 = bcr.top, y2 = bcr.bottom,
        pts = [[x1,y1],[x1,y2],[x2,y1],[x2,y2]],
        pt = svg.createSVGPoint(), pt2,
        bb = {}, u;

    if(x1===0 && x2===0 && y1===0 && y2===0){
        return {x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0};
    }

    for(var i=0; i < 4; i++){
        pt.x = pts[i][0];
        pt.y = pts[i][1];
        pt2 = pt.matrixTransform(mtr);
        if(bb.xmin === u){
            bb.xmin = bb.xmax = pt2.x;
            bb.ymin = bb.ymax = pt2.y;
        }else{
            if(bb.xmin > pt2.x){
                bb.xmin = pt2.x;
            }else if(bb.xmax < pt2.x){
                bb.xmax = pt2.x;
            }
            if(bb.ymin > pt2.y){
                bb.ymin = pt2.y;
            }else if(bb.ymax < pt2.y){
                bb.ymax = pt2.y;
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        x: bb.xmin,
        y: bb.ymin,
        width: bb.xmax - bb.xmin,
        height: bb.ymax - bb.ymin
    };
}
```